# Cannot find module 'next-auth/adapters' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

this is the code

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { env } from "@/lib/env";
import type { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const authOptions:NextAuthOptions={
    adapter:PrismaAdapter(prisma) as Adapter,
    providers:[
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: env.GOGGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_SECRET_ID,
        }),
    ],
};


const handler= NextAuth(authOptions);

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

import type { Adapter } from** "next-auth/adapters";**
it shows
Cannot find module 'next-auth/adapters' or its corresponding type declarations.

i try the older version of nextAuth and the latest version but it didn't work it out